# How to three. Js 3 d diagram its texture for you want pictures by the formation of the material?

Tags: webgl, three.js

```
var crateTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'img src="1.jpg' );
var crateMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: crateTexture } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( THREE.GeometryUtils.clone(cubeGeometry), crateMaterial );
 cube.position.set(-60, 50, -100);
scene.add(  cube );
```

I tried the following this but is black, and did not show what I loading in pictures

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be causing this for you.

Your first line should be the following:

```
var crateTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '1.jpg' );
```

Note that we are giving `loadTexture` a normal URL and not an HTML attribute.

The next most likely cause of why you are seeing no texture is that you are viewing the page locally from your file system rather than through a webserver. If you are viewing the page from the file system (aka a URL starting with `file://` instead of `http://`) you will get an error when the page tries to load the texture.

In chrome the error looks like this:

```
Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.
```

The last reason you may see no texture is that you are not constantly rendering the scene. Make sure you have some sort of `animate()` function which will continuously render the scene.

It actually takes the browser a split second of time to download and load the texture (and this happens asynchronously) , so if you only render the scene once you will most likely render it before the image has even been downloaded.

I have a live demo of a working version of your code [here](http://antonpantev.com/so-related/threecubetexture/). And [here](https://github.com/antonpantev/so-related/blob/master/threecubetexture/index.html) is a link to the code.